# Why thread still work with deleted variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference

I expect to crash program with this code:

```cpp
void f(int& ref)
{
    for (auto i{0}; i < 0xfffff; ++i)
    {
        std::clog << i << ":" << ref++ << std::endl;
    }
}

void run(void)
{
    int n = 10;
    std::thread(f, std::ref(n)).detach();
}

int main(void)
{
    run();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
}
```

I have GCC 9.3 and compile above program with default parameters. When i run the program i expect to crash which in `void f(int&);` function we no longer have local `int n;` variable decelered in `void run(void);` function, but it's clearly run the program and increase `ref` variable each time and printed until the 3 second sleep in main function get over. Where i do wrong ?

Comment: you should not expect things when your code is wrong. Appearing to work correctly is the worst incarnation of an error

Comment: What you're seeing is simply the result of [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: @idclev463035818, Can you explain more please ? i know it has to crash but it continues to work.

Comment: " i know it has to crash " how do you know that? I am not aware of any rule that would require your program to crash here

Comment: @idclev463035818, I say that because of the local `n` variable well be destroyed when function `f` is running in another thread. So when we use variable `n` the result must be crashing.

Comment: i am really curious, " the result must be crashing. " why do you think so?

Comment: @idclev463035818, I explained twice, the variable `n` in `f` function is not available, so when i try to increase it or read it, it must be result in crash because there is no variable.

Comment: really not trying to be snarky, so I'll also tell you: There is no such guarantee, nothing in the C++ standard tells you if you do that your program will crash

Comment: no you didnt explain, you just said if you do this it **should** crash, but why should it crash?

Comment: @idclev463035818, How i must know that ? i mean UB in above program. I'm sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: if you cross a streed when the lights are red, you will not necessarily hit by car. It just means you should not cross the streets when there are red lights (and when you do you might be hit by a car)

Comment: ...as any analogy it isnt perfect, because in C++ you also should not cross the street on red lights even when you made sure that there is no car coming and nobody is watching you

Comment: @idclev463035818 If it's not a duplicate you should post it as answer. I think there is not much to add.

Comment: @GhasemRamezani Try `int a[2]; a[5] = 5;`. It's a similar problem and it won't crash most times, too.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I am pretty sure that there are many very similar questions, but they are hard to identify as duplicate. Anyhow, I'll wrap it up as answer

Comment: _Where i do wrong?_  You went wrong here: "When i run the program i expect to crash".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) because you are using a reference to access an object whose lifetime already ended. There are some special rules regarding extension of lifetime when binding to a `const` reference, but that does not apply here.

The C++ standard **never** guarantees that your program will crash if you make a mistake. The C++ standard only specifies what you get when you compile and run valid code. There would be no gain from specifiying things like "If you dereference a null pointer you will get a segmentation fault". Instead the standard specifies what is valid code and mostly stays silent about what happens when you write invalid C++ code. In a nutshell, this is what undefined behavior is.

Repeating a comment of mine:

If you cross a streed when the lights are red, you will not necessarily get hit by car. It just means you should not cross the streets when there are red lights (and when you do you might be hit by a car).

As any analogy this isn't a perfect one. Even if you don't see a car coming and you know that you will not get hit, you should not "cross the street" when "the lights are red". That is because code that relies on undefined behavior like yours may appear to work today, but tomorrow with a different compiler, different version of same compiler, or even same compiler targeting a different platform, bad things may happen.